# React apollo: Access cache to know how many items have been queried in pagination

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am using React Apollo to query with GraphQl. I have a list with pagination with `skip` and `limit`. Sometimes the user can go to page 10 and click on an item to go to another page.

The query is like this:

```
query($limit: Int, $skip: Int, $sort: String, $order: Int, $fields: [String]) {
  sales(limit: $limit, skip: $skip, sort: $sort, order: $order, fields: $fields) {
    count
    pages
    items {
      ...item
    }
 } 
}
```

When the user goes back in browser history to the list, it queries with the default variables. Skip 0, limit 15.

How can I access the cache to make sure the query gets all cached items? Is there a way to do this without having a global state to store the limit/items you have cached?

I tried with this to read the cache but it does not work because the cache is empty on first render and there is no query with this schema:

```
const cache = client.readQuery({
    query: gql`
            query Sales {
                sales {
                    items {
                        id
                    }
                }
            }
        `,
});
```

Comment: `When the user goes back in browser history to the list, it queries with the default variables. Skip 0, limit 15`
Does this means refreshing or reloading the page ?

Comment: I use react-router-dom and navigate with history.push() or history.goBack(). It does not refresh the window. @Kaslie

Comment: I see, do u set these field skip, limit in the query params or other storage?
As far as i know, apollo only save the cache results, but won't save your skip or limit variables.